# how to add subscript symbol in naming of Venn diagram

Tags: r

I have a plot like this

```
library(VennDiagram)
grid.newpage()
draw.pairwise.venn(area1 = 20, area2 = 12, cross.area = 3, 
                   category = c("TT1*", "TT2*"))
```

I want to know how I can put the names with the name being TT and 1* or 2* becomes subscript?

Is also possible to change the postion of the name ?

Comment: The simplest way to get basic subscripts like this is to use the [Unicode characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts) TT₁ & TT₂

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out `expression`. Adding brackets will create subscript.

```
draw.pairwise.venn(area1 = 20, area2 = 12, cross.area = 3, category = c(expression('TT'["1*"]), expression('TT'["2*"])))
```